# Load time weaving in grails

Tags: spring, grails, aop

I'm trying to use load time weaving in a Grails project in order to be able to serialize and deserialize an object and to have automatic injection of spring dependencies. After some searching I found an [easy example](http://fadishei.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/spring-load-time-weaving-on-tomcat-does-it-really-work/) and that seems to work as expected. But after applying the same configuration to a simple Grails project I get a lot of errors. For example:

```
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@413a2870] error at org/springframework/web/servlet/theme/AbstractThemeResolver.java::0 class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.AbstractThemeResolver' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
```

To test this I created a new grails project and changed the applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect" weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

In this file I also created a new bean:

```
<bean class="be.testweaving.Person" scope="prototype">
    <property name="name" value="Timon"/>
</bean>
```

This defines a prototype for the `Person` class and injects the value `Timon` into the `name` property.

I package this as a war using `grails war` and deploy this on a tomcat server. This tomcat has the `org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar` in his lib directory and after the deployment I see a huge list of the errors I mentioned above.

Has anyone been able to configure load time weaving in Grails?

Comment: When I follow the example mentioned above and deploy this in the same tomcat, I can see the example working and the weaving seems to work fine. Could anyone tell me wether there is something grails specific that prevents the weaving from taking place?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: If not solved already: It sounds like a class loader issue. Try to put all dependencies of your grails app into your war file and remove all non-tomcat related jars from the tomcats lib directory. Also take care of having the same version of Spring everywhere (your the applicationContext.xml indicates use of 2.5 but instrument version of 3.0.5-RELEASE mentioned).

Comment: Load time weaving requires a -javaagent cmd-line argument on the VM. Did you set this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just inject your property via metaclass?

```
class ExampleBootStrap {
 def init = { servletContext ->
     Person.metaClass.constructor = {  
         def person = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Person) 
         person.name = "Timon"
         person
     }
 }
}
```